# Will the SIM card for an iPhone 12 fit into the cellular SIM slot on an iPad Mini version 6?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sim

Apple Genius in the Stanford Apple store just told me "yes".

Apple's online chat help (live agent) just told me "no".

Does anyone know the actual correct answer?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both devices take nano SIMs.

From everymac.com's pages on [iPhone 12](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/specs/apple-iphone-12-global-a2403-specs.html)

[image]

and [iPad mini 6](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-mini-6th-gen-2021-a2568-wifi-cellular-specs.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for one of the most comprehensive, well sourced, and helpful answers I have seen in the 13+ years I have been on stack exchange.   Thank you nohillside!

Comment: @PetervdL Thanks. To be honest, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463725/9058 got the same information directly from the source (Apple).

Answer (score 2):

Apple publishes this information on their [web site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202645).

All models of the iPad Mini are nano-Sim.  All iPhones model 5 and later are nano-Sim.

Answer (score 1):

SIMs come in standard sizes, usually supplied inside a credit-card-sized sheet.
You just break out the relevant size for the device.

I've never known any new device need a larger SIM than the one it's replacing.

One thing to note - the software/firmware of SIMs is constantly updated - but only when you ask for a new SIM from your provider. It's always smarter to get a new SIM for a new device. I've never known any provider charge for a new SIM.

[image]

Image from https://www.4g.co.uk/news/sim-card-sizes-standard-micro-and-nano-explained/

This is how they're delivered, each body size is inside the larger, so you just snap out the relevant size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation and visual aid.   What I am really asking is "Can I use the SIM from my iPhone 12, in my iPad mini v6?"   I don't have 3 SIMs of different sizes.  I just have one SIM in my iPhone 12, and want to know if it fits in the iPad Mini (that I haven't bought yet).     The image and the link help me move forward, thank you.

Comment: that really depends on your phone service provider, I am able to use my French SIM card on my old iPad for 4G

Comment: No new device is ever going to need a larger SIM than an older device. So, even if the new one needs a smaller SIM, you can just break the smaller section out of the older, larger sim.